# Why does downloading a large file with wget seem to consume nearly all available RAM?

Tags: memory, memory-usage, wget

I am trying to download a file of 580MB with the following simple `wget` command:

```
wget http://example.com/file.ext
```

The server has 16 GB installed RAM of and during the entire download the memory usage increase from 10% to up to 99%.

How is it possible that download a file of 580MB requires more than 14GB of RAM?

Comment: Why do you think that wget is using all your memory?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Exactly. Seems like there is false correlation happening here.

Comment: No, there is not any false correlation.
The server does not contain any file and has been configured today.
The memory usage is always 10% and is constant.
When i launch the wget command for the large file the memory usage progressively increase during the download and arrive up to 99%.

When the download is finisched the memory usage decrease progressively to 10%.

This happens EVERY TIME i launch the wget command.

Comment: Again, why do you believe this is so? Show your evidence.

Comment: “This happens EVERY TIME i launch the wget command.” On your machine. Which means there is something happening. Perhaps if you could provide OS & `wget` version numbers so we can help debug?

Comment: Also, `man top`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are downloading the file to `/dev/shm` or a `tmpfs` file system wget, by itself, shouldn't be using gigabytes of memory.  Heck, it shouldn't even be using megabytes worth.

It is highly unlikely that `wget` is consuming that much memory.  How are you checking its usage?

If you run `top -o RES` it will sort by memory (non-shared) utilisation.  Ignore the `VIRT` column, look at the `RES` column for the size.  If a unit (KB, MB, GB) isn't displayed then it's most likely reporting in KB.

You can use `ps aux` (or a myriad of other flag configurations) to get memory utilisation for each process.   Look at the `RSS` column for the non-shared memory size for the process.  This will report the size in KB.

If it helps, here is an easy way to show how much is being used.  Open up two shell sessions to your server.  On the first run this while loop:

```
while true
do
  ps -eo size,command | awk '/wget/&&!/ps.*awk/{print $1, "KB", $2}'
  sleep 5
done
```

On the second session run your `wget command`.  On the first terminal session you should see output similar to this:

```
$ bash loop.sh
516 KB wget
516 KB wget
516 KB wget
516 KB wget
... (so on and so forth until you CTRL-C out of the while loop)
```

It will run `ps` every five seconds and tell you exactly how much memory is being used by that process.

If it is using gigabytes worth of memory... well, there's something really, really wrong with `wget` or the shared libraries it uses.  At that point you'll need to turn to `lsof` or `strace` or other similar utilities to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is with the way memory is being looked at.

Assuming a Linux or similar system is being used there are 2 parts to the memory - actual memory used by applications and buffer/cache.   I suspect what you are seeing is the buffer/cache memory filling up, and showing little free memory - of-course this is somewhat misleading because as soon as its required the memory can be re-allocated to other programs that need it.

IE This has nothing to do with WGET and everything to do with the way Linux manages memory - it is "mostly harmless", as the memory used by cache/buffers can be recovered on demand.